# Ruby on Rails Rollback except a given model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

I am running on Rails 3.2.22 and I can't get transaction/rollback working. This code should always print "WORLD" but actually, it will never work if **raise** is called. But according to [Rails doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html), it should always reach there. My question is - is there a way how to save @pb status into a database? If I decide to save the status before rollback, it will not save. If I save it after raise, it will not execute. Is there a way around that? For example, is it possible to allow a function to "jump out of block while in a block"?

```
    @pb = ProgressBar.create(..)
    ..
    def import(user)
    Thread.new do
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        errs = operation(user)
        Rails.logger.info "HELLO"
        if errs.any?
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
      end
      Rails.logger.info "WORLD"
      @pb.failed_import
    end
  end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Rails.logger.flush` after `Rails.logger.info "WORLD"`?

Comment: @JacobVanus 3.2.22

Comment: @JacobVanus that would not actually help, the problem is that pb.failed_import will never be called

Comment: That's what I'm getting at. Are you sure @pb.failed_import isn't being called? Because the thread is ending, the logger data could get lost before its written. `flush` should write it immediately and let you know if you're flow control is really broken. Also, threads behave differently in different versions of ruby. What do you get from `ruby -v`?

Comment: I am 100% sure. Checked even by trying to create a record in DB. Didn't get there. My version of ruby is 2.1.5

Comment: Try with Thread.abort_on_exception = false; Thread.new do end

Comment: @GeorgeMorris did that worked?

Comment: Ups, sorry I have just tried it but it sadly didn't.

Comment: But anyways, I have realized one thing - progress bar in a transaction is impossible because the transaction has to finish therefore updating progress within the transaction is impossible.